# Skipping through elements on SVG bar graph in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've build a method in java for selenium, whereby I want to click on an SVG bar graph and click on the first 3 bars (screenshot below)
[image: Screenshot]
I've done this by implementing the below code:

```
    public static void barChartSelector(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    genericControls.waitCommands.fluentWaitOnBarChartSelector(driver);
    WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.className("highcharts-series-group"));
    genericControls.waitCommands.fluentWaitOnBarChartSelector(driver);
    List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.tagName("rect"));
    genericControls.waitCommands.fluentWaitOnBarChartSelector(driver);
    children.get(0).click();
    children.get(1).click();
    children.get(2).click();
    genericControls.waitCommands.fluentWaitOnRelationalBarGraphDisplay(driver);
}
```

However, what I'm finding is that I sometimes get this error:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at genericControls.graphSelectors.relationalBarChartSelector(graphSelectors.java:34)
    at Reports.collections.breachReportCompletedFunctions(collections.java:30)
    at Reports.programMain.main(programMain.java:37)"
```

It looks like when I run the `get` command, the graph isn't always indexed the same from page to page, so on some pages it will work and some pages it will fail. My thinking is that I need to implement a `for` loop so that I can still run the `children.get(X).click();` event, but instead of falling over if the code cannot find the first event, it loops through until it finds the `get` command that returns a result.

Please could someone advise me how I might convert my code above into a `for` loop so that it can look for any of the `children` elements that might meet the criteria? This will help me with my understanding of how to implement this in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that the problem is here:

```
List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.tagName("rect"));
```

The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown because `children` doesn't always contain 3 WebElements.

Try replacing with this:

```
List<WebElement> children = parent.findElements(By.tagName("rect"));
genericControls.waitCommands.fluentWaitOnBarChartSelector(driver);
for (WebElement child : children) {
    if (children.indexOf(child) > 2)
        break;
    child.click();
}
```

NB, I'm assuming that there may be more than 3 "rect" WebElements, and that you're only interested in clicking the first 3. Remove the if statement if you want to click all rect elements.